# Internet Explorer 11 redirect not working in GET request

Tags: get, internet-explorer-11, http-status-code-302

I have a GET request fetching data that is redirected (302).
Using IE 11 the re-direct does not hit the server and the result of the first request (with identical query string parameters) is returned. Chrome, Firefox and Edge do not have the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to simply append a &counter=[counter] parameter to the query string and have the [counter] increase by one on every call.

Example:

```
first call: [query string]&counter=1
second call: [query string]&counter=2
third call: [query string]&counter=3
```

etc.